# Bootstrap Circle Buttons

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create circle buttons using `Bootstrap` but its not working as it should be. Here is what I am doing:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">4</button>
```

And it is showing the result like this:

[image]

I referenced [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/circle-button) website. my version of `bootstrap` is `3.3.5`. Any help?

Comment: just add `border-radius` to `50%`

Comment: Did you include the css? I'm not sure this is standard, could be wrong though

Comment: Check for any overridden CSS.

Comment: Border radius worked magically. Thanks @Amit Singh

Comment: @Amit singh, put this in the answers so that i can accept it.

Comment: @Saani - if you included the css `ofcourse i did` then you have something wrong with your code - the class is fine but the css is not being referenced or, as Manoj says, overridden - therefore adding another border-radius is adding code that's not needed

Comment: At first, I thought the same when I was trying it in my website code that i m working on but then I tested it with the pure bootstrap css and in a separate file, and even then it didn't work, God know why!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do this..

**CSS**

```
.btn-circle {
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/Jyjjx/45/)

```
    .round-button {
    width:25%;
}
.round-button-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:10px solid #cfdcec;
    overflow:hidden;

    background: #4679BD; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button-circle:hover {
    background:#30588e;
}
.round-button a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:50%;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    line-height:1em;
    margin-top:-0.5em;

    text-align:center;
    color:#e2eaf3;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-default">4</button>`

Comment: doesn't work that way, I have got the answer in the comments below the question that is by changing the border-radius to 50%.

Comment: that makes the default bootstrap button not circle button

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default rounded-circle">4</button>
```